# PDO: Call to undefined method DB::query()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to get to hang of PDO but not having much fun at the moment. I bet it's something really simple as well.

**EDIT: What would be a better way to go about doing this? i.e instead of wrapping it in a class?**

classes/DB.class.php:

```
<?php

// DB.class.php

class DB {

    protected $db_name = "PDO";
    protected $db_user = "root";
    protected $db_pass = "root";
    protected $db_host = "localhost";

    // Establish Connection to Database.

    public function connect() {

        try {
            $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}

?>
```

includes/global.inc.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'classes/DB.class.php';

// Establish Connection to Database.

$db = new DB();
$db->connect();

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/global.inc.php';

$STH = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($STH->fetch());

?>
```

Comment: You'd need to use `$db->DB->query()`. Your class isn't extending the PDO class, it's simply wrapping it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have DB property and `query()` method in your DB class. Add it like this listing:

```
class DB
    {
    protected $db_name = "PDO";
    protected $db_user = "root";
    protected $db_pass = "root";
    protected $db_host = "localhost";
    protected $DB = null;

    // Establish Connection to Database.
    public function connect()
        {
        try
            {
            $this->DB = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->db_host.";dbname=".$this->db_name."", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
            } 
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

    public function query()
        {
        return $this->DB->query();
        }
    }
```

The better way would be to use some ORM library or bare PDO object - it's quite friendly.

Comment: Hi, I get the following: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PDO/classes/DB.class.php on line 28

Comment: Was there any error message from PDO that it couldn't connect to the database? Seems like PDO object was not instantiated.

Comment: Keeps saying Undefined variable for $db_name, user, pass and host?

Comment: You have `echo $e->getMessage();` part in the code - I mean this message which should be shown on the page when you run the code.

Comment: Updated answer - missing `$this->` parts.

Comment: Brings back no errors. However when I change it so that it does have a error, it still doesn't report an error.

Comment: Have you tried adding `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` at the beginning of global file?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class DB extends PDO {

    protected $db_name = "PDO";
    protected $db_user = "root";
    protected $db_pass = "root";
    protected $db_host = "localhost";

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            parent::__construct("mysql:host={$this->db_host};dbname={$this->db_name}", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}

$db = new DB;
$db->query('SELECT * FROM something');
```

Also, I added the `$this` keyword in front of your members, because `$db_name` and such were not declared in the method scope.

If you do not want the connection to be initiated when the object is created, you could do:

```
class DB extends PDO {

    protected $db_name = "PDO";
    protected $db_user = "root";
    protected $db_pass = "root";
    protected $db_host = "localhost";

    public function __construct() {
        // do nothing
    }

    public function connect() {
        try {
            parent::__construct("mysql:host={$this->db_host};dbname={$this->db_name}", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}

$db = new DB;
$db->connect();
$db->query('SELECT * FROM something');
```

**Important note:** Normally, when overriding methods in children, you need to specify the same method signature as the parent (or you'll get an E_STRICT error). Fortunately, this doesn't apply to core classes, probably to allow overrides like this.

Answer (score 1):

The object instantiated as $db does not have the method query. There is probably not a need to wrap the PDO object within another object, but if you are going to do that, you need to make sure all methods are accessible.

Comment: "*There is probably not a need to wrap the PDO object within another object*" - why not? I do that for years, and IMHO it is very handy.

Comment: @binaryLV: In that specific use case, there isn't any. Inheritance is better. The adapter pattern is indeed useful when you build an abstraction layer though.

Answer (score 1):

your class DB has no method query! you could do it this way:

```
<?php

    // DB.class.php

    class DB {

    protected $db_name = "PDO";
    protected $db_user = "root";
    protected $db_pass = "root";
    protected $db_host = "localhost";

    private $_db;

    // Establish Connection to Database.

    public function connect() {

        try {
            $this->_db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->db_host.";dbname=".$this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public function __call($name, array $arguments) {

        if(method_exists($this->_db, $name)){
            try{
                return call_user_func_array(array(&$this->_db, $name), $arguments);
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                throw new Exception('Database Error: "'.$name.'" does not exists');
            }
         }
     }

}

?>
```

With the magic function `__call()` you can pass all functions that PDO supports to your newly created PDO Object.

Comment: Magic methods are very bad way to correct programmer's errors.

Comment: I don't want to correct programmer errors, I just want to include PDO functionallity in the DB class.

Comment: And this is not correcting it, because if he call PDO method incorrectly using such "proxy" it will give him "undefined something" error and he won't know what is going on. I'm not going to downvote your answer, just to say, that it isn't good way to solve the problem.